# Import Spreadsheet with field name listed vertically/per row

Tags: excel, import

I need to import a spreadsheet, but the field names (title) are listed vertically. Is there any way I can import it?

e.g.

```
field 1 | axy
field 2 | 30
field 3 | ax21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharePoint won't be able to create a list from a spreadsheet in that format. Nor will you be able to copy and paste it into quick edit mode. (Theoretically you would be able to copy and paste it, but it would not work as intended.)

Luckily there is an option to rotate data in Excel so you should be able to correct the format and then import it into SharePoint.

[Transpose (rotate) data from rows to columns or vice versa](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744)